# Unable to access .jar file with .desktop

Tags: command-line, .desktop, execute-command

I have a `Minecraft.desktop` on  /home/myuser/Escritorio
(Where myuser i put my username and Escritorio means Desktop in spanish)

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Minecraft Launcher
Comment=Minecraft Launcher
Exec=java -jar ~/Descargas/Minecraft.jar
Terminal=false
Categories=Game;
```

And a `Minecraft.jar` in `/home/myuser/Descargas` (Descargas = Downloads)

Permissions of `Minecraft.desktop`: `-rwxrwxr-x`

Permissions of `Minecraft.jar`: `-rwxrwxr-x`
When i execute the `.desktop` file nothing happens.
But when i execute the `.desktop` via terminal with the next command:

```
grep '^Exec' Minecraft.desktop | tail -1 | sed 's/^Exec=//' | sed 's/%.//' &
```

It says:

```
Error: Unable to access jarfile ~/Descargas/Minecraft.jar
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `~` in a `.desktop` file, it will not expand. Only use absolute paths. You need to change the `Exec=` -line to:

```
Exec=java -jar /home/myuser/Descargas/Minecraft.jar
```

In case the directory includes spaces:

```
Exec=java -jar "/home/my user/Descargas/Minecraft.jar"
```